# Probability that the sum of 40 numbers from $X$ ~ $Unif(-1/2,1/2)$ is greater then 3?

Tags: probability

There are $40$ independent random variables, $X_i$ ~ $Unif(\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ for $i \in \{1,2,...,40\}$. What is the probability that their sum is greater then 3?

My attempt at a solution is definitely incorrect.

By letting $Y = X_1+X_2+...+X_{40}$ all we will have to do is find $P(Y>3)$, but thats the same evaluating $1 - P(Y\leq3)$. This can be solved since we know that the pdf is $f(x)=\frac{1}{1/2-(-1/2)}=1$. Putting this all together we get:

$$P(Y>3)=1-P(Y \leq 3)=1-\int_{-20}^{3} 1 dy$$
I got a lower bound of -20 since the lowest value you could pick everytime is $-1/2$ so just multiple it by 40 to get a minimum sum value. The problem is that this evaluates to a negative value. more specifically $-22$.

Can someone tell me what my mistake is?

Comment: The distribution on the sum is very far from uniform (and it certainly isn't confined to the interval $\left[ -\frac 12,\frac 12\right]$).  with so many terms, I'd just use the normal approximation.

Comment: For i.i.d. continuous random variables each with PDF $f_X(x)$, the PDF of $X_1+X_2$ is the convolution of $f_X(x)$ with itself.  For a sum of 40 you need a 40-fold convolution of the original PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Your pdf for $Y$ is wrong.  The sum of $40$ independent uniform random variables has a rather complicated distribution which can be given by a piecewise function
which is a polynomial of degree $39$ in each interval $[k, k+1]$, $-20 \le k \le 19$.  However, you can approximate this random variable by a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_{40}=\sum\limits_{i=}^{40} X_i$ where $X_i\sim U(-1/2,1/2)$ with mean $\mu=0$ and variance $\sigma^2=1/12$ Then $$Z=\frac{S_{40}-0}{\sqrt{40}(1/12)}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$ approximately by the Central Limit Theorem. Thus $$P(S_{40}>3)=P\left(\frac{S_{40}-0}{\sqrt{40}(1/12)}> \frac{3}{\sqrt{40}(1/12)}\right)$$

which  is then computable via the Normal table